# Adding option to large file in outlook web add-in

Tags: javascript, xml, outlook-web-addins

I was wondering if we could add an option to this dialog:

[image: Large file dialog]

I tried catching the event but there is no such event (event and launchevent).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature: adding an extra option to attachment dialog, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.